# How to make a command randomly fail

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Okay so on my bot I have a beg command but the peoblem is I want it to sometimes fail.

For example one time it might say "Someone gave you $5" but if it fails it would say "Famous Person: NOPE"

The code below chooses a random text from a file where all the text is. 
Is there anyway to mke it randomly fail so a user does not get money?

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const { prefix } = require("../../botconfig.json");
const db = require('quick.db')
let bal = require("../../database/balance.json");
const fs = require('fs');
const cooldowns = new Map();

const humanizeDuration = require('humanize-duration');

//Set cooldown


module.exports = {
    name: "beg",
    aliases: [],
    category: "economy",
    description: "Gets you money",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const cooldown = cooldowns.get(message.author.id);
        if (cooldown) {
            const remaining = humanizeDuration(cooldown - Date.now(),{ units: ['s'],round: true });
        let cEmbed = new RichEmbed()
          .setColor("RANDOM")
          .setTitle("Slow down, cmon!")
          .setDescription(`You dont want to be like a cry baby! You will be able to beg in \`${remaining}\` just you wait!\n\nWhile you wait why not follow our [Twitter](https://twitter.com/switchoffical)`)
  return message.channel.send(cEmbed)
            .catch(console.error);
        } else {
            if(!bal[message.author.id]){
                bal[message.author.id] = {
                    balance: 0
                };
            } 
            const Jwork = require('../../beg.json');
            const JworkR = Jwork[Math.floor(Math.random() * Jwork.length)];
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 3;
            let curBal = bal[message.author.id].balance 
            bal[message.author.id].balance = curBal + random;
            fs.writeFile('././database/balance.json', JSON.stringify(bal, null, 2), (err) => {
               let embed = new RichEmbed() 
                 .setColor("RANDOM") 
                 .setDescription(`**\ ${message.author.username}**, ${JworkR}  **${random}**`) 
               message.channel.send(embed)
               if (err) console.log(err)
            });
            //Adds the user to the set so that they can't talk for a minute
            cooldowns.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 10000);
            setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to make it fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do is run a `Math.floor((Math.random()-0.001)*4)` store it to a variable. Now you have a random number from 0 to 3 (4 different numbers/outcomes). And then check whether your new variable equals 0. `if(failChance === 0)` if it's true just *don't* do the add bal cmd.

Example:

```
...
} else {
   var failChance = Math.floor((Math.random()-0.001)*4);
   if(failChance === 0){
       message.channel.send('FAILURE');
       return;
   }
   if(!bal[message.author.id]){
...
```